# Will an SDL Tridion license survive a backup/restore?

Tags: licensing

We have a SDL Tridion CM and CD server license on one of our server machine. Machine will get formatted and we need to reinstall the SDL software again. I just wanted to check with you if any formatting done and reinstalling won't impact the license as we will take backup of all the license key files and apply the same.

Please let us know what all prerequisite would be required for this case where we need to reinstall the SDL Tridion again on same machine.

Comment: Unrelated to the license, but if you plan to copy the CM configuration files you should make sure they are decrypted first. Otherwise it will be unable to read the configuration after the format.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the license is usually linked to the machine name, so if you reformat the server, and install it using the same name, you shouldn't see any problems.
If you wish to change the machine name, you should contact Tridion Support, they will be able to issue you a new license file.

Note that, if you change any hardware (like adding processors,...) your license may also stop working, in case it's bound to the number of processors.

Answer (score 4):

The Content Manager server prerequisites are covered in the online documentation (login required) here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A6CBE401-9EB7-4534-9362-4B15B19B290E
(They are probably far more comprehensive than an answer you would get here.)

You may also want to check whether you have a Content Porter license on your machine, and take a backup of that too.

It may be worth taking a backup of the complete Tridion folder, and making sure that you have copies/source code for all custom pages, GUI extensions, hotfixes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Usually companies have policies for Machine names, e.g my company don't use same machine name after format or hard-disk change, Name is taken dynamically from a central machine to avoid any conflict with other machines in organisation.

So after format we have to request updated CMS,  Broker(when **CD** also installed on same machine), CP license from SDL whenever System is formatted. so accordingly you might have to request updated license(s) as Harald mentioned.